# Sonar Plugin editing the .erb file on the fly?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Is it possible to edit the widget.erb file on the fly without restarting the Sonar server?  I am thinking it is no different than any other front end file, but since the plugin is not actually "exploded" there is no way to edit the file without opening the jar and editing it.

However if there was a way, it would allow designing the widget that much quicker!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it's possible to edit plugin web content on the fly. Please look at this page : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extend+Web+Application.

You can either :

- For widget : Edit the method RubyRailsWidget#getTemplatePath() in order to return the absolute path to the widget file, rather than the class path (See more in Widgets -> Development mode)
- For web app : Edit the file war/sonar-server/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb and set the absolute path to your ruby application by replacing the property config.plugin_paths (See more in Applications -> Development mode)

Comment: Julien,

That looks promising!  So after making the change to return the absolute path, do we then open the jar and edit the file inside it?

Comment: I've answered on your post on the SonarQube's dev mailing list : http://markmail.org/thread/rrjrwd5m7lnxjo4u